# DatagridView (WindowsForm) colums to keep width on inital size if filtering data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a WinForm DatagrdiView that is bound to a DataTable. The 4 colum widths are set as "AllCells" (3x) and Fill (1x). It is possible to filter the data via user input (textbox), so anytime a user types the data within the grid is filtered to this input so the results in the grid changes.

So the current behavior is every time a char is typed that, with the filtered data also (as set), the column width changes. This looks fuzzy and not good. Any ideas how i can prevent the initial width column? I don't want the columns to "jump around". Fix sizes are not possible because the main form can be resized like usual in windows.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved it as follows: After dynamically loading the data into the grid, I manually changed the properties of all the columns that had as `AutoSizeColumnMode` `AllCells` in the code to `None`.

```
myGrid.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
```

Now I have the desired behavior. Maybe this info is still useful for someone.